# Facebook sharing meta tags for redirects

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to update some old iOS/Android Facebook sharing code to work with the new sharing API.  The old API used to let you specify a URL and an image, so users see the image in the FB feed and if they click on it, it takes them to the URL.  I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing under the new API.

This is for a game program.  The way it worked is if a user got a high score - say, 1000 points - I would bring up a share dialog, specify a URL for a stylized "1,000 points!" JPG as the image, and specify the game's home page as the destination URL.  Under the new approach, I'm not allowed to specify the image, instead they want me to specify it in the Open Graph metadata for the target URL.  This is the solution I came up with under the new approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NAME OF GAME</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='GAME WEBSITE'" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="NAME OF GAME" />
<meta property="og:image" content="URL OF JPG" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL OF JPG" />
<meta property="og:description" content="NAME OF GAME" />
</head>
</html>
```

This *mostly* works.  When a user shares a link to the above web page, they get the JPG image showing their score, and if you click on the JPG it redirects you to my game's website - however, in the news feed Facebook is now overlaying the URL of the redirected page and a little arrow to show that a redirect will take place.  If I can eliminate the ugly overlays and just show the image, my work is done.  If you have any insights they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't do it this way any more. You need to create individual URLs.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, I'm making a separate HTML page for each possible score graphic, but the thing I'm having trouble with is getting it to redirect the user to the game's website if they click on it in Facebook.  The HTML I posted above is intended to achieve that but it isn't working.  Are you saying there's no way to do it?

Comment: I added the following line:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='URL for Game Page'" />
to the header and I set the og:url equal to the og:image, and now it does redirect me, but not before it loads the image first.  I'm thinking I might just need to remove the body, I will try that next.

Comment: Okay, I've made a little progress on this, so I updated the question - I just need to solve one last problem and then it's perfect.

Comment: That overlay is due to the fact that you now specified the image URL as `og:url`, so Facebook tries to fetch the meta data from there. But there is no meta data of course, so some generic information is shown instead. You should set `og:url` to the address of the document itself, that carries this meta data.

Comment: The problem is, the document is a full web page, and I'd need to make like four thousand copies of it for every score a person could get - this is what I'm trying to avoid, I'd like to display the user's score in their newsfeed and then have it go to the game's web page if someone clicks on the item in their news feed.

Comment: That's why you don't make every single one of those URLs output the full HTML, but the necessary meta data only. And then when a human visitor click on the link on Facebook and lands on such a URL, you simply redirect them to the intended actual target right away.

Comment: That's what I've done with the HTML in the post, it just has the metadata and a redirect.  The problem is, if I change "og:url" to point to the landing page, Facebook pulls the metadata from the landing page instead of my HTML above (so it shows the first JPG it finds on the landing page, _not_ the JPG displaying their score).

Comment: _"The problem is, if I change "og:url" to point to the landing page, Facebook pulls the metadata from the landing page instead of my HTML above"_ - that's why I keep telling you, over and over, that you should not do that ... `og:url` needs to point to the URL that returns this exact specific set of meta data - what is so hard to grasp about that ... !?!?

Comment: I think you are not understanding the problem.  I want a large set of about 4000 custom images that each direct the user to a single web page.  I don't want 4000 copies of the web page, each with a different image - that would be prohibitively large.  The solution you are describing would require me to do that, because each og:url would have to point to web pages with different metadata.

Comment: If you have a solution which does what I'm requesting, could you post it as an answer and if it works, I will accept it as the answer?  Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to _physically_ create 4k different files. You're talking as if you've never heard of having a server-side script dynamically creating output, based on URL parameters ...? If that's the case, then go read up on that.

Comment: _"because each og:url would have to point to web pages with different metadata"_ - yes, it has to. But with _only_ that meta data, not the full content of your website - that's why I said you _redirect_ the human visitor to the actual site URL.

Comment: Are you suggesting a PHP script which generates the metadata for the header, but the body just has the game page?  That might work.

Comment: No, I am suggesting `<body></body>` ... are you grasping _any_ of what i am trying to tell you?

Comment: CBroe, you've made it clear that this is super, super easy.  Could you post an answer to my question to illustrate how easy it is?  Not a fragment like <body></body>, but an actual solution to the problem?  If not, then thank you for your time.

Comment: Care to explain what part of this essentially two-step process you are having that much trouble with? Step 1: Create a script, that based on URL parameters outputs a minimal HTML document containing the necessary OG meta data for title, description and thumbnail. Step 2: Add code that redirects human visitors to what you are referring to as the "game page" - either client-side, via JavaScript, or server-side (but the latter will need an exception for the Facebook scraper, based on its User-Agent.)